# Python C Extension on Windows. Error: not found vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, c, windows

I followed [this link](https://tutorialedge.net/python/python-c-extensions-tutorial/) to make Python Cextension .

When I try Ubuntu, I get the .so file without problems but when I try the windows, this error comes out :

> Error: unable found: vcvarsall.bat
>
> Microsoft Visual C ++ Compiler for Python installation required.

I did the installation but gave the same error.
How to compiler c file to in python? How to convert .dll file ?

Comment: `vcvarsall.bat` is a script that makes the visual studio compiler `cl` available in command line. If your script cannot find this file, you can try to add its parent directory to your path.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`

is the location of `vcvarsall.bat`, at least on my system and installation (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2017). You need to find your `vcvarsall.bat` and add it to your environment variable `path`.

Here's a [visual tutorial](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) on how to add to your `path` in Windows 10. After you add the containing folder of `vcvarsall.bat` to your `path`, you should not have an error anymore.